# Read text below barcode pytesseract python

Tags: python, tesseract

I am trying to get the number below a barcode in an image. I have tried the same code with some other images and works fine but not for that image
Here's the image
[image]

And here is the code till now

```
def readNumber():
    image = cv2.imread(sTemp)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
    invert = 255 - opening
    data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
    print(data)
    try:
        data  = re.findall('(\d{9})\D', data)[0]
    except:
        data = ''
    return data
```

And I used it using this line

```
readNumber()
```

Here's another example
[image]

This is the last example I promise
[image]

I tried this with the third example and it works

```
img = cv2.imread("thisimage.png")
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)
#gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(blur)
print(txt)
```

But how I adopt all the cases to work with the three cases?
I tried such a code but couldn't implement the thrid case

```
import pytesseract, cv2, re

def readNumber(img):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    try:
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
        #txt  = re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]
    except:
        thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 4)
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="digits")
        #txt  = re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]

    return txt

# M5Pr5         191876320
# RWgrP         202131290
# 6pVH4         193832560
print(readNumber('M5Pr5.png'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any preprocessing methods or configuration for the input image. Since there is no artifacts in the image.

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("RWgrP.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
print(txt)
```

Result:

```
202131290
```

My pytesseract version is `4.1.1`

Update-1

---

The second image requires [preprocessing](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

If you apply [adaptive-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html):

[image]

But the output also consists of unwanted characters. Therefore if you set the configuration to digits, the result will be:

```
193832560
```

Update-2

---

For the third image, you need to change the adaptive method, using `ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C` will result in:

```
191876320
```

The rest are same.

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("6pVH4.png")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 4)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="digits")
print(txt)
cv2.imshow("thr", thr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the code but I got `202131280` instead of `202131290`. How can this be improved?

Comment: When I edited this line `txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry, lang='eng', config='--psm 6 --oem -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')`, I got correct result. Thank you very much.

Comment: Here is my [result](https://imgur.com/a/EqQ4u9h). Maybe updating or downgrading to the version 4.1.1 makes your job easier. Anyway I'm glad you solve the problem.

Comment: I have used this line to upgrade `pip install pytesseract==4.1.1` but when using this line to check the version `pip freeze | findstr pytesseract`, I found it `pytesseract==0.3.6`

Comment: The latest version is [0.3.7](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/). 4.1.1 is the output of `print(pytesseract.get_tesseract_version())`

Comment: I got this `4.0.0-alpha.20180109` but how I upgrade to 4.1.1 to test your code.

Comment: You know `alpha` is not a stable-version. I guess `pip install pytesseract` will upgrade to the 0.3.7 or (4.1.1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please have a look at this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146007/upgrade-pytesseract-in-python

Comment: I have put another example that didn't work for me. Can you please have a look? How can I be able to widen the width of the image (I think the numbers should be separated by some spaces in between)?

Comment: I've updated my answer, see `Update-1` for the answer

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much. Best and Kind Regards.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you. When I tried the first image with the second code (The update), I got empty string. Is there a way to handle both cases in one code?

Comment: I could implement both cases in the code. Thank you very much.

Comment: I have added a third example and I promise this to be the last one. I tried both codes with it but didn't return the result correctly.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the code in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151483/ ? Please adivse me if there is a better approach.

Comment: No problem for me, ask as much as you can, you need to change the `adaptiveMethod` for the third image. See the answer under `Update-2`

Comment: The issue is you need a deep-learning-based method. The method which is invariant to all changes in the input image. Maybe you should google `east-text-detector`

Comment: Thank you very very much for the great support in that issue. Thanks a lot. I wish I could increase the rep points again and again and again ..!!

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183322/get-numbers-from-cropped-image-pytesseract?