# Check if string is of nine digits then exit function in python

Tags: python

I have a function in python that returns different output of strings (Text). And I have different parts that I should check for the string and if the string is of nine digits or contains 9 digits then I need to perform in the function to exit the function at the point
I am newbie at python and I don't know how to exit the function at specific point if a criteria is achieved.
For example

```
s = 'oodf 191876320x sd'
print(any(char.isdigit() for char in s))
```

This checks if the string has digits. I need to add another criteria to make sure there are adjacent 9 numbers. and if `True`, then exit the function at the point.

The code that I am working on is to read number from image (with three different cases of manipulation)
This is my try and I welcome any ideas

```
import pytesseract, cv2, re

def readNumber(img):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
    if bool(re.search(r'\d{9}', txt)):
        return re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(blur)
    if bool(re.search(r'\d{9}', txt)):
        return re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]
    thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 4)
    txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="digits")
    if bool(re.search(r'\d{9}', txt)):
        return re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]
    '''
    
    try:
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gry)
        #txt  = re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]
    except:
        thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 51, 4)
        txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, config="digits")
        #txt  = re.findall('(\d{9})\D', txt)[0]

    return txt
'''
    
# M5Pr5         191876320
# RWgrP         202131290
# 6pVH4         193832560
print(readNumber('M5Pr5.png'))
print(readNumber('RWgrP.png'))
print(readNumber('6pVH4.png'))
```

The related question is on that link [Read text below barcode pytesseract python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66126756)

Comment: Give your fairly high rep level, you should know that requirements-only questions are not very welcomed here.  Can you also include your current code?

Comment: Please use some punctuation marks in the question and  share a minimal reproducible code.

Comment: The current code is complicated and I just need one point if exists. Is there Exit Function in python?

Comment: What are you asking for, how to count digits in a string, or how to exit a function?

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry for the confusion. I have added the code till now and I welcome any ideas to improve my learning skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use regex. The below regex will match given that the string contains 9 adjacent digits.

\d{9,}

Comment: Thanks a lot. I used this `import re

s = 'oodf 191876320x sd'
print(bool(re.search(r'\d{9}', s)))`

Comment: you're welcome. Note that the preceding comma dicts whether you allow for matching on "atleast" 9 adjacent digits, or if you don't use it you only allow for "exact" 9 adjacent digits

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please have a look at the code and tell me if I am on the right way or not?

Answer (score 1):

to exit a function do you mean to return back from where it was called?

if so then use

```
if len(stringVarible)==9:
   return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply return from the function when the condition is satisfied:

```
# Suppose the string is stored in text variable

if len(text) == 9:
    return
```