# Get numbers from cropped image pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I have a cropped image and I am trying to get the numbers on that cropped image
Here's the code I am using

```
image = cv2.imread('Cropped.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
invert = 255 - opening
data = pytesseract.image_to_string(invert, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)
```

Here's the sample cropped image
[image]

All what I got some numbers and not all of them. How to enhance such an image to be able to extract only the numbers?

I tried the code on this image but doesn't return correct numbers
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily solve this with three-main steps

---

- 1. Upsampling
- 2. Applying [simple-threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)
- 3. set configuration to digits

---

**Upsampling** for accurate recognition. Otherwise tesseract may misterpret the digits.

**Threshold** Displays only the features of the image.

**Configuration Setting will recognize the digits

---

|  | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Upsampling | [image] |
| Threshold | [image] |
| Pytesseract | 277032200746 |

---

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnbmf.png):

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img1 = cv2.imread("kEpyN.png")  # "FX2in.png"
gry1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(h, w) = gry1.shape[:2]
gry1 = cv2.resize(gry1, (w*2, h*2))
thr1 = cv2.threshold(gry1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr1, config="digits")
print("".join(t for t in txt1 if t.isalnum()))
cv2.imshow("thr1", thr1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Update:

---

Most-probably a version mismatch causes extra words and digits.

One-way to solving is taking a range of the image

For instance, from the thresholded image:

```py
(h_thr, w_thr) = thr1.shape[:2]
thr1 = thr1[0:h_thr-10, int(w_thr/2)-400:int(w_thr/2)+200]
```

Result will be:

[image]

Now if you read, result should be like this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Puq.png)

```py
277032200746
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tested it and I got `277032200746y014L`.

Comment: Hmm why `y014L`? Thats very strange. Could you please test with adding `config=--psm 6 digits`?

Comment: I tried `config="--psm 6 digits"` an I got `2770322007465oW014L`

Comment: I've updated the answer, hopefully this time you will get only the digits. Please see the answer under Update section

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot for your awesome update. But I didn't get this line `thr1 = thr1[0:h_thr-10, int(w_thr/2)-400:int(w_thr/2)+200]`. On what basis the numbers 200 and 400 is put?

Comment: Those digits are just constant to make the digit center of the image. The idea is to make the digit center so it won't mix with arabic words.

Comment: Oh, congrats. So getting only digits is working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried such lines and this worked fine too `import pytesseract, cv2, re

img = cv2.imread("kEpyN.png")
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config="digits")
print(re.sub('[^0-9]', '', txt))` But I prefer your approach.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you. I have updated the question as I tried the code on another example but doesn't return the expected.

Comment: I think the issue is you are still using the alpha-tesseract version. For me the new image is returned as expected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great support. I find a way to enhance the image that helped me to get correct results. Best and Kind Regards.